# Windows Phone 7 in vs2010

Tags: windows-phone-7

When i tried to call .Net web service http://....using windows 7 API's

Its working fine. But if i used with same web service https://... i got

security error like *There is a problem with this website's security certificate*.

Help me out for this query...

Comment: You might want to update the question title to an actual title that reflects what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a test certificate or other certificate not supported by the phone.

If that's the case then your question is a duplicate of [Making a WP7 HttWebRequest POST with an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401546/making-a-wp7-httwebrequest-post-with-an-untrusted-cert)

The solution to your problem is that you can't and must get a certificate from a trusted root certificate authority.

Answer (score 1):

The site you're accessing needs to have a valid certificate from an issuer recognised by the platform. The latest list of these issuers I've seen is here.

[push notifications from authenticated services](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/62133.aspx)

Note Geotrust will give you a 30 day trial certificate which is handy for testing.

**Update:** [New documentaiton of trusted certificate issuers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Added documentation released yesterday by Microsoft.