# How to install root certificate on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, certificate

Just can not find how to install root certificate on Windows Phone 7. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401546/making-a-wp7-httwebrequest-post-with-an-untrusted-cert/4406296#4406296):

> ```
> You can do this by emailing the RootCA to the user of the phone. They click
> on the attachement and it will prompt them to ask if they want to install
> the certificate on the phone.
> ```

I've not tried this though and so can't say for sure if it works.

As there is no way to install a cert programatically I'd look to use a cert from a source which is already trusted by the phone instead.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there is no way to programatically install the certificate?

Comment: Being able to programmtically install root certificates could lead to potential security security issues. Based on the intention of building a secure and predicatbel platform I doubt this would ever be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use CharlesProxy on Windows Phone. What I did was the following:

1. Go to charlesproxy.com/charles.crt (file will be downloaded)
2. Save file as .cer instead of .crt
3. E-mail file to an e-mail account that can be openen with an e-mail application on WP (somehow you can't download e-mail attachments using a webbrowser on WP)
4. Click on attachment (once for download, twice for installing)
5. Have fun proxying.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you're trying to implement, this may also be of interest.

[Using an Exchange Account With a Custom Certificate](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2010/07/31/WP7-Using-Exchange-Account-With-a-Custom-Certificate.aspx)

Comment: I'm just trying to debug an application using Charles Proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: I've emailed the certificate and it asked me if i want to install it, but still does not seem to work - IE always says that certificate is not valid.

Comment: I have been apparently been able to install a self signed cert generated using IIS7.5 be emailing it to myself. I say apparently because from memory it offered no positive or negative feedback on the result. Attempts to install the certificate via the browser did produce an error though.