# Error in WebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, webclient, httpwebresponse

I'm working with WebClient for some time now. (using the Mango SDK)

Each time I have an error, the error message is always "Not Found". Either the error is due to  login problem, server or page not found. Any error code >= 400 cause the same Exception with the same message and no data.

I tried to use the *WebRequest/WebResponse* but it seems the problem is always the same.

I mean, I know how to write it correctly in C# (for desktop), but on **windows phone**, I have no way to access the error code nor the response body.

I found many posts talking about the problem, but no solutions are pointed.

Does anyone have a solution or a workaround (even a dirty one...) I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That (very misleading) error is often caused by an underlying HTTP error.

If you are using HTTPS, it could be because it's a self-signed (or otherwise [unsupported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)) certificate. You can temporarily get around this by [emailing the certificate to an account on the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473653/how-to-install-root-certificate-on-windows-phone-7), but this won't fly in the marketplace.

If the requests aren't HTTPS, you can run [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to find out what the underlying error is. (Pro tip: The WP emulator will only the use Fiddler if Fiddler was running when it started up so you may have to close it down).

To access the data, you need to get the `WebException` (it may be the `InnerException` of what is being thrown) and then you can access the [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: @SirLeamont - Have you tried accessing the response via WebException?

Comment: A simple cast from e.Error to a WebException and everything works fine. Seems I was looking at this for too long...