# How to programatically install a Root CA certificate on a Windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, ssl, certificate

How to programatically install a Root CA certificate on a Windows phone? This question is analogous to this one: 
[How to install root certificate on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473653/how-to-install-root-certificate-on-windows-phone-7), Though, I'd like to know how to programatically do this.

Thank you.

Comment: This is really the kind of thing that an OS shouldn't let any application do silently, without explicit consent from the user (preferably from a settings interface in the OS itself).

Answer (score 0):

As said in the question you linked, there is no way to install a certificate programatically.

Comment: This answer doesn't add much to the question... :-(

Comment: Well, you said you want to know how to programmatically do this, the answer is simple: you can't. The best workaround I can suggest is to store the certificate on a web server. When the user starts your application for the first time, display an explicative message, then use a WebBrowserTask to open the certificate with Internet Explorer, so the user can install it.