# Handling HTTPS request in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

We have ASP.Net generic handlers that support HTTPS requests only.

Example: `https://{domainname}/userservice/getfriends.ashx`

Please suggest a solution for processing the https requests in Winows Phone 7.1 using `HttpWebRequest`. When I am binding the https images (for example `https://{domainname}/userserivce/23232.jpg` only), it's raising the error.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Do you check it on the device or on the emulator? The emulator doesn't support https protocol.

Comment: does the domain have a valid SSL certificate? If not, it won't work unless you import the certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Is your SSL certificate signed by a [Root Certification Authority trusted by Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521150%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (example: Verisign) or is it a self-signed certificate?

If it's not from a valid trusted root certification authority, export the signing root certificate, send it by email to the device, and then install the certificate; check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4473799/358596) for more info.