# How to get Thumbprint or Public Key of Issuer Certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have created a self signed CA certificate which we use to sign other certificates for SSL purposes. These certificates will be installed in other servers which we do not have access to and will be strictly to communicate with other clients like mobile applications.

When these clients (written in .NET) make a request to the servers using HTTPS we get the "Invalid certificate received from server" error because the CA cert is not a trusted CA on that client.

We want to bypass this security using the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, but only if the certificate being used was signed by our CA certificate.

I can check the `certificate.Issuer`, but that can easily be spoofed by anyone. How can I get the Thumbprint or Public Key of the Issuer certificate of the invalid certificate? If I can get access to that I can easily compare it to the one I know is valid and ignore the certificate error and continue on with the request.

**UPDATE**

I think I am getting closer. It looks like what we're looking to do is not doable so went a slightly different direction.

Using the `X509Chain` we can verify whether the certificate is a child of the CA using the code below:

```
var caCert = new X509Certificate2(@"[path]\MyCA.cer");

var newChain = new X509Chain();
newChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
newChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(caCert);

var res = newChain.Build(certInQuestion);
```

`Build()` still returns false (as expected because the CA is not trusted on the client), but now `newChain.ChainStatus[0].Status` is returning `UntrustedRoot`. Based on my testing this means the chain validated because if I supply a different CA Certificate it fails with `InvalidChain`.

In conclusion, that tells me that if the Status is `UntrustedRoot`, the certificate *was* created with our CA certificate and thus it's valid, anything else it's a fake one!

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: If I have the public key of the Issuer, maybe I can do something to validate the certificate against that key?

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong solution. You should install your self-signed certificate as a trusted CA certificate in all clients, or better still just get it signed by a CA that is already trusted. Don't write code for this.

Comment: installing the CA certificate in all clients is not manageable. I would love to be able to sign it by a trusted CA, but there business decisions on why we're doing it this way.

Comment: A *very poor* business decision. Have it reviewed. Getting it signed will cost you fifty bucks, take about 24 hours, and work immediately, correctly, and securely. Writing code and testing it etc will cost thousands, take days if not weeks, and introduce security risks that you can't even quantify.

Comment: it's not a single certificate. These certificates are installed on the customer's servers, so it would be a certificate per customer. The business decision is to make the installation of the server piece as simple as possible and going through the process of getting SSL certs every year is not an option they want their customers to go through.

Comment: Unless you can tell me there is a way to create SSL certs in house from a certificate issued by a trusted CA...

Comment: @JonasStawski You need to become a 'tiny CA', with your own certificate. There are lots of tools for this available for download.

Comment: are you talking about this http://www.ghacks.net/2009/09/16/create-your-own-certificate-authority-with-tinyca/ 
Are the certificates created trusted?

Comment: @JonasStawski Yes, that's an example. The only certificate that needs to be trusted is your own CA certificate which is created first, as the root of all the others. Then you just install that root cert in all the clients. Because it is then trusted, all the certificates it signs are trusted transitively.

Comment: that's exactly what we're doing. We created our own CA certificate and issue other certificates with it. We are trying to avoid installing the CA into all the clients for user simplicity. By avoiding the invalid certificate (only if it was signed by our CA) then we can do so. Do you see any security problem with it, concerns?

Comment: The bottom line is we want to encrypt the data traveling through the wire and if we know the SSL Cert is ours then we can trust it. Unless you can tell me that someone can make a man in the middle attack and use a cert that will validate with my CA Cert. In that case then I might be wrong

Comment: @JonasStawski Major security concerns start with the fact that you don't know how to implement it, or even whether you *can* implement it; and then that you don't know whether it will be secure if you do implement it, as shown by not knowing whether to check the public key or the thumbprint, and by asking in your edit whether your assumptions are correct. You have to get your root cert to be trusted, and when the SSL handshake completes check that your cert is at the root of the peer cert chain. You're doing it back to front. If I was management and I saw this I would immediately reassign.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links with info and some tools to generate free public and private keys:

https://www.igolder.com/pgp/

https://www.igolder.com/pgp/generate-key/

I think EJP's solution is the most acceptable. @EJP, can you give us some examples of applications that can help us become a "tiny CA".

Comment: [TinyCA](http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/) is one (hence the name). [XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) is another (cross-platform too).

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for that kind of tools ...!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure this this is what you're looking for but it might push you in the right direction. Here's a PowerShell script I use to find a cert that I just created and extracted using MAKECERT.EXE & CERTMGR.EXE:

```
# get certificate thumbprint
$appCertificate = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certificateFullPath

Write-Host "  .. adding certificate to local machine root" -ForegroundColor Gray 
& $ExeCertManager /add $certificateFullPath /s /r localMachine root
Write-Host "  Certificate installed on local machine" -ForegroundColor Gray 

Write-Host "  .. exporting private key for certificate" -ForegroundColor Gray 
Get-ChildItem cert:\\localmachine\my | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $appCertificate.Thumbprint} | ForEach-Object {
    $CertPfxName = (Get-Item -Path $certificateFullPath).BaseName
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but I'm trying to validate the public key or thumbprint of the issuer of a certificate programmatically within a mobile application.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that a possible solution would be that you could email the certificate, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4473799/674700.

Comment: yes, I'm aware I can install CA certs, but would prefer to stay away from it at this point. The mobile clients are iOS now and will be Android and WP later on.